How to show bottomsheet inside a composable after receiving FireBase Notification
the code I shared that is fine , am able to get the notification data on logcat, but I want to show notification data in one of my composble screen. I did not get How I can pass notification data from firebaseNotificationService class to my composble screen.
class FireBaseNotificationServices(
    private val notificationRepository: NotificationRepository = Graph.notificationRepository
) : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    private val firebaseViewModel: FirebaseViewModel by lazy {
        FirebaseViewModel()
    }

    private val orderViewModel: OrderViewModel by lazy { OrderViewModel() }

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
       
        Log.d(TAG, "From: ${remoteMessage.from}")

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: ${remoteMessage.data}")
            Log.d(TAG, "Message ID: ${remoteMessage.messageId}")

            orderViewModel.setNotificationData(NotificationDataModel(id = 0, notification_type = "new order", notification_data  = remoteMessage.data.toString()))



            // Check if data needs to be processed by long running job
            if (needsToBeScheduled()) {
                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use WorkManager.
                //scheduleJob(remoteMessage.data)
            } else {
                // Handle message within 10 seconds
                handleNow()
            }
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        remoteMessage.notification?.let {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: ${it.title}")
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: ${it.body}")
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.notification?.body.toString())
            firebaseViewModel.setNotificationData(it.title.toString(), it.body.toString())
        }
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }

    private fun needsToBeScheduled() = true

    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        sendRegistrationToServer(token)
    }

    private fun scheduleJob(remoteData: MutableMap<String, String>) {
        // [START dispatch_job]
        val data = Data.Builder()
        data.putString("orderId", remoteData["id"])
        val work = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker::class.java).setInputData(data.build())
            .build()

        WorkManager.getInstance(this)
            .beginWith(work)
            .enqueue()
        // [END dispatch_job]
    }

    private fun handleNow() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Short lived task is done.")
    }

    private fun sendRegistrationToServer(token: String?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "sendRegistrationTokenToServer($token)")
        setFirebaseToken(token.toString())
    }

    private fun sendNotification(messageBody: String) {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        val requestCode = 0
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            requestCode,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE,
        )

        val channelId = "cws.pos.app"
        val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        val notificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                channelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT,
            )
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        val notificationId = 0
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build())
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService"
    }

    private var scope = MainScope()

    private fun setFirebaseToken(id: String) {
        val dataPref = DataPref(context = applicationContext)
        scope.launch {
            dataPref.setFirebaseToken(data = id)
        }
    }

    internal class MyWorker(
        appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters,
    ) :
        Worker(appContext, workerParams) {
        private val orderViewModel: OrderViewModel by lazy { OrderViewModel() }

        override fun doWork(): Result {
            val orderId = inputData.getString("orderId")
            Log.d(TAG, "doWork: $orderId")

            orderId?.let {
                orderViewModel.setNotificationData(NotificationDataModel(id = 0, notification_type = "new order", notification_data  = orderId))
            }
            return Result.success()
        }
    }
}


You can use ModalBottomSheet https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/components/bottom-sheets

I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Hi @AlexMamo , the code I shared that is fine , am able to get the notification data on logcat, but I want to show notification data in one of my composble screen. I did not get How I can pass notification data from firebaseNotificationService class to my composble screen

You can use Local Broadcast Receiver to pass data from the messaging service class to composable activity.  In activity you can use ViewModel to pass data to desired composable.

Hello @AbdullahJaved , how I can do that , do you have reference please ?

https://chatgpt.com/share/67126996-9570-8009-8867-fb02cdd2c9ff
You can get an idea from this

@AbdullahJaved it is working fine, but onReceive method calls multiple time(approx 4 times) on single broadcast
